# Inserting symbols into Office Ribbon XML controls

Tags: xml, vba, ms-word, ribbon

I am building a ribbon tab for Word 2010 from scratch using XML stored within a Word template's customUI14.xml file. I am creating buttons that when clicked insert the text for various symbols (the euro, section mark, etc.) The code for inserting the symbols works fine, but I cannot get the labels of the XML controls to display these symbols. For example, I tried this to display a euro symbol:

```
 <group id="rxGroupSymbols" label="Symbols">
      <button id="rxbtnEuro" label="&#128;" size="normal" onAction="rxshared_click">
 </button>
 </group>
```

But when using ASCII symbol equivalents the `"&#128;"` does not generate the euro symbol, nor do other variations such as `&amp;#128;`.

How can I get the Ribbon XML to display these characters on Office ribbon controls? Thanks.

Comment: Hey, I just want to do the same thing, I need a button in my ribbon to insert some symbols, can you give more details how to achieve that?

Comment: @Pedro77 -- If Google and SO don't already have this answer (or the answers don't make much sense), post a question that shows the code you've tried and the specific symbols you are trying to insert via your ribbon control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that XML allows only five special characters (character entities) as detailed in [this Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references). The solution was to use the `getLabel` attribute:

```
 <group id="rxGroupSymbols" label="Symbols">
      <button id="rxbtnEuro" getLabel="getlabel" size="normal" onAction="rxshared_click">
      </button>
 </group>
```

And send the ASCII symbol into the XML as a string:

```
 Public Function getlabel(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef Label)
      Label = Chr(128)
 End Function
```