# Inserting "&" symbol into Label property of Office Ribbon XML controls

Tags: excel, vba, ribbonx

I am building a ribbon tab for MS Excel 2016 from scratch using XML stored within a customUI14.xml file. I created buttons having the "&" special character into the button label (i.e. "Cut & Paste", or "Trades & Models", etc...). The code for inserting the symbol works fine, but I cannot get the labels of the XML controls to display this symbol.

I used both the methods described in the post [Inserting symbols into Office Ribbon XML controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451331/inserting-symbols-into-office-ribbon-xml-controls) but nothing seemed to work.

I'm not state that those approaches don't work at all (I tried with other symbols and they worked - i.e. with the same symbol "€" of the above mentioned post the solution provided in the past post works well)

```
<menu id="T1G2M1-PGSTRGY" getLabel="RibSetCtlLabel" size="normal" itemSize="normal" 
imageMso="ChartInsertGalleryNew" screentip="Settings &amp; Filters" 
supertip="Options to use during What-If Analysis." getEnabled="RibSetCtlEnabled">
```

with this call-back procedure

```
Public Function RibSetCtlLabel(ctl As IRibbonControl, ByRef Label)
  Label = "Settings " & Chr(38) & " Filters"
End Function
```

Both approaches ("&" symbol directly into the xml text or into the string applyed as result of the call-back procedure) fail tu run properly

I expected to have the button label = "Settings & Filters" but "Settings 
 Filters" is displayed

The workaround solution is required to be run both on x32 and x64 Office 2016 version

Comment: I could be wrong, but I thought using two in a row worked... like `Settings && Filters`

Comment: Tks braX... I tried to do that in the screentip string but it doesn't work. It works so only if I use a callback function approach, but I consider this as a workaround because I don't need of a dynamic label for my ribbon button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to duplicate a special character in the string to get it visible on the ribbon UI. For example:

```
Ribbon && Fluent UI
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works with call back function only

Comment: Is there a way for directly use the "&" special character into xml code? It would be a lighter code approach :)

Comment: Didn't test: `&#38;#38;` replacing ampersand :-)

Comment: &#38;&#38; worked but writing &amp;&amp; is more readable

Answer (score 2):

In the XML use:

```
&amp;&amp;
```

Comment: Worked flawlessly!
This should be the accepted answer